# Creating an array.push doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a Javascript course and the excersise is:

Write a range function that takes two arguments, **start** and **end**, and returns an array containing all the numbers from start up to (and including) end.

So I wrote this nice peace of code:

```
var range= function(start, end) {  
    var numbers = [];
    for(start; start == end ; start++ ) {                            
        numbers.push(start);  
    };        
    return numbers;
}; 

console.log(range(3,10));
```

But the outcome is this: [ ] --> which looks like the array is empty

Comment: `start == end` should perhaps be `start <= end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to change the [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to:

```
for(; start <= end ; start++) {
```

The condition is an expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration, if this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed.

Comment: Ah thanks, now i got it! If I state start == end it gets a FALSE boolean, so it must be equal OR smaller than.. Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `for` condition

```js
var range = function(start, end) {
  var numbers = [];
  for (start; start <= end; start++) {
    numbers.push(start);
  };
  return numbers;
};

console.log(range(3, 10));
```

Comment: Thanks, you're answer is right as well... the == must be replaced by <=

Answer (score 0):

your `for` loop has a false statement:

```
 for(start; start <= end; start++)
```